# rosdep init and rosdep update?

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know if rosdep init and rosdep update that we perform during ROS installation make any changes outside the ROS environment? like does it update or modify the debian packages or any other non-ROS components? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255165/rosdep-init-and-rosdep-update-?/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-02-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, `rosdep init` puts a file in `/etc/ros/rosdep/`, if this is "outside of the ROS environment" for you.
`rosdep update` fetches the new rosdep definition files and stores them somewhere too.

Other than that, `rosdep` does nothing as long as you don't do a `rosdep install <PKG>`. This will then install the required dependencies that are specified in the package. This can be other released ROS packages or third party packages as debian pkgs or from any other package manager, e.g. pip.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-02-21**:
Thank you. But does rosdep update updates the package list of other package managers too or does it just update the available ROS package list?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-21**:
@sam26: it does not install any package or change anything besides the files that @mig already mentioned (ie: `/etc/ros/rosdep`) and a cache in your `$HOME`.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2017-02-21**:
Just the rosdep definitions. Those are "remappings" pointing to specific, distro dependent version. They are defined, e.g. [here](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/base.yaml). Thus, the rosdep key `ace` points to `ace` for arch and `libace-dev` for debian...

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-02-21**:
Thank you!

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-02-22**:
@mig @gvdhoorn But when I look at the sources that rosdep sources.listcontains, it points to packages that are present in universe and multiverse as well ( non-ROS packages ). So rosdep update would update these non-ROS  packages right (just like apt-get update) ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-22**:
`rosdep` only uses a `20-default.list` in `/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d`, and that does not contain any mention of `universe` or `multiverse`.

But in any case: `rosdep` itself will *never* install or upgrade anything, that is the pkg mgrs job, only after you *accept* what it wants to do.